# What is the remainder when $x^7-12x^5+23x-132$ is divided by $2x-1$? (Hint: Long division need not be used.

Tags: polynomials

What is the remainder when $x^7-12x^5+23x-132$ is divided by $2x-1$? (Hint: Long division need not be used.)

The Hint is confusing!

Comment: So what do think?

Comment: Take a look at this [Polynomial remainder theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_remainder_theorem)

Answer (score 5):

Since $\deg(2x-1)=1$ then the remainder is a constant. Write

$$P(x)=(2x-1)Q(x)+r$$
so what's $P\left(\frac12\right)$?

Answer (score 4):

Let $f(x)=x^7-12x^5+23x-132=g(x)(2x-1)+r(x)$

since, deg(divisor)>deg(remainder)

and given deg(divisor)=1, therefore, deg(remainder)=0, or, its a real number.

put $x=\frac{1}{2}$

to get $f(\frac{1}{2})=r$

Answer (score 3):

Because in this case, the remained is a real number:
$$f(x)=(2x-1)g(x)+r$$
Therefore $f(\frac12)=0\cdot g(\frac12)+r=r.$

Answer (score 1):

You can use Horner schema to evaluate it. For an explanation of this algorithm read [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/962303/roots-of-this-third-degree-polynomial/962337#962337). In your case you have

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline &1&0&-12&0&0&0&23&-132 \\\hline\frac12 &0&\frac12&\frac14&-\frac{47}{8}&-\frac{47}{16}&-\frac{47}{32}&-\frac{47}{64}&\frac{1425}{128}\\\hline &1&\frac12&-\frac{47}{4}&-\frac{47}{8}&-\frac{47}{16}&-\frac{47}{32}&\frac{1425}{64}&\color{red}{-\frac{15471}{128}}\\\hline\end{array}

which, by the way, uses the same idea of the other answers, but it avoids you many calculation with high powers.

Comment: this is the way to go.